# Proof that $\mathcal{O}_X(D(f))=A(X)_f$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am confused by the highlighted line in the following proof given by Gathmann in his set of [algebraic geometry notes](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2019/alggeom-2019.pdf):

[image]

In particular this seems to be saying that if two functions $f$ and $h$ vanish at precisely the same points, then they are the same function. But surely $f(x)=x^2$ and $h(x)=x$ vanish at precisely the same points. Am I missing something here? Why can we identify $f_a$ and $h_a$ in proof?

Comment: Hmm... do you know the fact that polynomials $f$ and $g$ in $K[x]$ have the same zero locus on an algebraically closed field $K$ if and only if $f$ is in the radical ideal generated by $g$ and vice versa?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Sure, but I don't see why that means $f=g$, which seems to be the implication in the highlighted part of the proof.

Comment: I see this is Proposition 1.10 (Hilbert's Nullstellensatz) in your notes. I think "we can therefore  assume" means "by the Nullstellensatz, after replacing $h_a$ and $f_a$ each by a suitable element of the radical ideal they each generate..."

Comment: @AlexKruckman So $h_a$ is in $\sqrt{f_a}$ by the Nullstellsensatz since $V(f_a)=V(h_a)$ implies $f_a\in\sqrt{(f_a)}=I(V(f_a))=I(V(h_a))=\sqrt{(h_a)}$. But then this gives us $f_a^n\in (h_a)$ for some $n\geq 1$, and so $f^n=kh_a$ for some other function $k$. But why from here can we say it suffices to replace $f_a$ by $h_a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a general way of looking at the argument that Gathmann is making. I'll assume we're working in affine space over an algebraically closed field.

**Claim:** Suppose a rational function $\varphi$ is defined on a distinguished open set $D(h)$. Then we can write $\varphi = \frac{g}{h^n}$ for some natural number $n$ and some polynomial $g$.

*Proof:* Since $\varphi$ is rational, we can write $\varphi = \frac{g'}{f}$, for polynomials $g'$ and $f$, and since $\varphi$ is defined on $D(h)$, $f$ does not vanish on $D(h)$. Thus, $D(h)\subseteq D(f)$, so $V(f)\subseteq V(h)$. By the Nullstellensatz, $h\in  I(V(h))\subseteq I(V(f)) = \sqrt{(f)}$. So there is some natural number $n$ and some polynomial $p$ such that  $h^n = pf$. Defining $g = pg'$, we have $\varphi = \frac{pg'}{pf} = \frac{g}{h^n}$. $\square$

If we don't actually care about the specific polynomial $h$, just the open set $D(h)$, we can go further and remove the power of $n$.

**Claim:** Suppose a rational function $\varphi$ is defined on a distinguished open set $U$. Then there are polynomials $g$ and $h$ such that $U = D(h)$ and $\varphi = \frac{g}{h}$.

*Proof:* Since $U$ is a distinguished open set, we have $U = D(h')$ for some polynomial $h'$. By the previous claim, we can write $\varphi = \frac{g}{(h')^n}$ for some natural number $n$ and some polynomial $g$. Let $h = (h')^n$. Since $D(h') = D((h')^n)$, we have $U = D(h)$, and $\varphi = \frac{g}{h}$.

Comment: I don't understand why we can replace $h_a$ by $h_a^n$. Doesn't this change the function? Since $h_a^n=pf_a$, we can multiply numerator and denominator by $p$ (since as you say it doesn't vanish on $D(h_a)$ to get $g_ap/h_a^n$, and renaming $g_ap$  $g_a$ gives us $g_a/h_a^n$. So then are we just "renaming" $h_a^n$ as $h_a$ since they are both elements of $D(h_a)$?

Comment: @ponchan The point is that the specific polynomial $h_a$ has played no role in the proof up to this point - only the open set $D(h_a)$ has. We introduced $h_a$ when we passed to the distinguished open set $D(h_a)$ containing the point $a$. But $D(h_a) = D(h_a^n)$, so we could just as well have used the distinguished open set $D(h_a^n)$.

Comment: @ponchan I've rewritten my answer to put the argument in more general terms. I hope that makes things clearer.